# <script> tag generated by salesforce after </html> tag

Tags: visualforce, validation, html, visualforce-template

I am building a website using templates and apex pages. In my apex page I have the option applybodytag and applyhtmltag set to false  and I use the `<head>` and `<body>` tags in my template page.

Every page that has a `<apex:form>` I get this piece of code after the closing html tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">Sfdc.onReady(function(){
    SfdcApp && SfdcApp.Visualforce && SfdcApp.Visualforce.VSManager && SfdcApp.Visualforce.VSManager.vfPrepareForms(["j_id0:fgTemplate:j_id67:j_id68:formnews"]);

});</script>
```

I understand that this code must be there, so my question is: Is it possible to change the location where the code appears, like before the `</body>` tag? W3C validator doesn't like `<script>` after `</html>`.

thanks

Comment: It is best practice and advisable to keep js and css in their respective files .js and .css and keep them as static resources for clean code. In your case, i assume it is salesforce default. You can leave it as is as long it would not affect or interfere in your page.

Comment: Hello Mark,Thanks for your answer. My concern is not that it affects my page. I know they don't. My problem is the w3c validator. Is there any way to change the location of the scrpit?

Comment: Some combinations of page options can cause this. Make sure you're not using your own HTML or body tags, or turn off the built in headers.